# Finding $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin 6x}{x}$

Tags: calculus

Why are we allowed to multiply the numerator and denominator by 6?

Also, when you multiply the numerator by 6 why doesn't the 6 multiply to 36?

Please share any techniques that can clarify how to evaluate this limit. The concept is confusing me now that I can't just either substitute, factor, or use the conjugate methods. [image]

Comment: A fraction does not change, if denominator and numerator are multiplied with the same non-zero number.

Comment: The 6 in $sin6x$ is not a factor

Comment: It it a radian?

Comment: Another example of why parentheses should not be omitted in  $\sin(\ldots)$ and other trig and logarithmic functions.

Comment: The important thing is, that $sin6x\ne 6sinx$

Comment: Robert is right here because the expression could also be interpreted as $sin(6)x$

Comment: if you have a calculator(in radian mode) can you graph $y1=\sin(x)$ and $y2 =x$ set both $x$ and $y$ windows to $[-1,1].$ what do the two graphs look like? what does that tell you?

Comment: The "why doesn't the 6 [in $6\sin(6x)$] multiply to 36" makes about as much sense as the classic joke $\frac{\sin\, x}{n} = \frac{si\not{n}\, x}{\not{n}} = six$. More helpfully perhaps: Let $f(x) = 1+ x + x^2$. Does $6f(6x) = 36 f(x)$? The situation with $6\sin(6x)$ is similar: $\sin(x)$ isn't linear, so you can't "pull out" the $6$.

Answer (score 2):

QUOTE Why are we allowed to multiply the top and the numerator and denominator by 6? END OF QUOTE
$$
\frac{\sin(6x)}x = \frac{6\sin(6x)}{6x}
$$
What has been been multiplied by $6$ here is just the numerator and the denominator.  It would be equally valid to multiply them both by $13$, thus:
$$
\frac{\sin(6x)}x = \frac{13\sin(6x)}{13x}
$$
but that would not get us where we want to go.  Your phrasing, "the top and the numerator and denominator" makes me wonder if you thought that *three* things were being multiplied by $6$.

QUOTE Also, when you multiply the numerator by 6 why doesn't the 6 multiply to 36? END OF QUOTE

Because we are nowhere multiplying $6$ by $6$.

Comment: Editing. Top meaning numerator. I fixed the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Why are you allowed to cancel out the 6 by the 6 you multiplied the numerator and the denominator with?

Comment: There is no cancelation of the $6$ in $\sin(6x)$ with anything. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

Notice:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{x} = \frac{6}{6} \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(6x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}6\frac{\sin(6x)}{6x}$$

Letting $u=6x$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{6\sin(6x)}{x} =\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{6\sin(u)}{u}$$
By L'Hospital's rule
$$\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{6\sin(u)}{u} = \lim_{u\to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{du}6\sin(u)}{\frac{d}{du}u} $$$$= \lim_{u\to 0}\frac{6\cos(u)}{1} = 6$$

Answer (score 0):

You're allowed to multiply any expression by $1$ without changing the expression.

But $\dfrac 6 6 = 1$.

(Regarding the substitution $\theta = 6x$, it isn't *wrong*, but it's an unnecessary step. It doesn't hurt, if it helps your understanding.)

Comment: Why don't we just simply use Lhospitals rule